# Pop-up does not load correctly. It needs page refresh every time

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

There is a link:

```
<div >
    <a href="#" class="newComment" onclick="bindAddSlots()">Add Details</a>
</div>
```

`onclick` method:

```
 function bindAddSlots() {
     debugger;
     if (!CheckforLogout()) {
         return false;
     }
     ClearPopUpControls();
     var dclg;
     dclg = $("#dvSchedulingProfile").dialog(
     {
         resizable: false,
         draggable: true,
         modal: true,
         title: "ADD Details",
         width: "400",
         height: "460"
     });

     dclg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
}

function ClearPopUpControls() {
    debugger;
    $("#ddlVisitType").val("Select Options");
    $("#SchedulingProfileDetails_Id").val("0");
    $("#dvSchedulingProfile").find("#txtNP").val("");
    $("#dvSchedulingProfile").find("#txtNS").val("");
    $("#dvSchedulingProfile").find(".lblAnnualVisitType").hide();
    $("#dvSchedulingProfile").find(".lblNP").hide();
    $("#dvSchedulingProfile").find(".lblNS").hide();
    $("#dvSchedulingProfile").find(".lblNPNumeric").hide();
    $("#dvSchedulingProfile").find(".lblNSNumeric").hide();
    $("#SchedulingProfileDetails_Id").val("0");
}
```

View Code:-

```
<div id="dvSchedulingProfile" style="display: none">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <table width="100%" height="75%" class="someclass">

             <tr id="AddVisitType">
                <td  class="black_label">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SchedulingProfileDetails.Id)
                    @Html.Label("Visit Type"):<span class="star">*</span>
                </td>
                <td  style="font-size: 12px;">
                    @Html.DropDownList("ddlVisitType", new SelectList((VisitTypeBo.LoadAll().OrderBy(x => x.VisitTypeName)), "VisitTypeName", "VisitTypeName"), new { @style = "width:250px;color:black" })
                <br/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td height="5">
                </td>
                <td style="color: Red; font-size: 12px; display: none;" class="lblAnnualVisitType"
                    align="left">
                    @Html.Label("lblAnnualVisitType", "Visit Type is required.")
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="5">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="black_label">
                    @Html.Label("Patient Slots(NP)"):<span class="star">*</span>
                </td>
                <td style="font-size: 12px;">
                    @Html.TextBox("txtNP", null, new { @style = "width:250px;", maxlength = 11 })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="5">
                </td>
                <td style="color: Red; font-size: 12px; display: none;" class="lblNP" align="left">
                    @Html.Label("lblNP", "NP is required.")
                </td>
                <td style="color: Red; font-size: 12px; display: none;" class="lblNPNumeric" align="left">
                    @Html.Label("lblNPNumeric", "Only Numeric values are allowed.")
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="black_label">
                    @Html.Label("Time Slots(NS)"):<span class="star">*</span>
                </td>
                <td style="font-size: 12px;">
                    @Html.TextBox("txtNS", null, new { @style = "width:250px;", maxlength = 11 })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="5">
                </td>
                <td style="color: Red; font-size: 12px; display: none;" class="lblNS" align="left">
                    @Html.Label("lblNS", "NS is required.")
                </td>
                <td style="color: Red; font-size: 12px; display: none;" class="lblNSNumeric" align="left">
                    @Html.Label("lblNSNumeric", "Only Numeric values are allowed.")
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="5">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td >
                    <input type="button" value="" class="save_bt" onclick="return SaveDetails()" style="margin-left:70PX;"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Now the problem is when the page loads and I click on the link the pop-up comes but for the pop-up to come out again I need to refresh the code and the problem is same in all the browsers. I have debug the code again and again but no error is coming and am totally confused, so somebody plz help me overcome this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying that once you close the pop-up that you can not then open it again until you have re-loaded the entire page?

Comment: exactly this is the problem.

Comment: So what code are you using the close the pop-up? I have a feeling that is where you problem will be.

Comment: You seem to be appending, but I cannot find a remove. Maybe your problem lies there? Just a hunch

Comment: for closing the pop-up i have code in onclick method of save button

Comment: You don't have to add seperate code to the onclick of the save button. the dialog() has a buttons property. Look at the example at https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation it may shed some light on the problem.

Comment: I don't think closing or removing the pop-up has any thing to do with the problem i think there is some problem with ClearPopUpControls()

Comment: But in that function you do nothing with the popup itself, you just hide the contents of the popup. The function does not seem to do anything weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when we close the dialog it is closed only but we need to destroy it so that the form doesn't have any remaining association with it. So we need some extra lines of code to decide what to do when we close the pop-up.

```
var dclg=$("#dvSchedulingProfile")
     dclg.dialog(
     {
         resizable: false,
         draggable: true,
         modal: true,
         title: "ADD Details",
         width: "400",
         height: "460",
         close: function () {
          dclg.dialog("destroy");
          dclg.hide();
          }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

what exactly is the need to append the dialog to the first element of the form?
if you remove that line, it should work fine I think..

because, first time it works properly since there in only one element with id `dvSchedulingProfile` and immediately after displaying the dialog, you add the same element again to the first element of the form, so next time there are two elements with same id, now jquery dialog doesn't work since it won't find a single element with given id..

Comment: i tried removing that line but the problem is still there